# The non-nullable local variable 'docRef' must be assigned before it can be used. Try giving it an initializer expression flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I get this when I try to get the snapshot on FBfirestore Error: **The non-nullable local variable 'docRef' must be assigned before it can be used.
Try giving it an initializer expression, or ensure that it's assigned on every execution path.**

code:

```
//Error here
DocumentReference docRef;

StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
                    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection('groups')
                        .doc(docRef.id)
                        .snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.data == null) {
                        return const ErrorScreen();
                      }
                      return Center(
                        child: Text((snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot<
                            Map<String, dynamic>>)['name']),
                      );
                    }),
```

Comment: Can you full  widget structure. It is showing the error because you didn't assign the value.

Answer (score 0):

This line declared a variable that has to be a `DocumentReference`, and can't be `null`:

```
DocumentReference docRef;
```

In order for this line to be valid, you have to assign a value to it right away, as otherwise it will be initialized to `null`, which isn't valid according to your own declaration.

---

If you want to allow `docRef` to be `null`, you need to declare it as

```
DocumentReference? docRef;
```

With this, `docRef` can either be a `DocumentReference` or it can be `null`, so you can leave it to `null` initially and give it a value later.

This then requires that every time you use `docRef`, you either check whether it is `null` (with an `if`), tell it how to handle `null` (with a `?`), or assert that you know for certain it can't be null (with a `!`).

In your code that'd look something like this:

```
DocumentReference? docRef;
```

And then:

```
docRef == null ? Text('No docref') : //  handle null here
  StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('groups')
        .doc(docRef!.id) //  it can't be null here anymore
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.data == null) {
        return const ErrorScreen();
      }
      return Center(
        child: Text((snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot<
            Map<String, dynamic>>)['name']),
      );
    }),
```

---

Another option is to declare the variable as:

```
late DocumentReference docRef;
```

The `late` keyword means that you don't initialize the variable right away, but that you promise to initialize it before you first read it. With this you don't need any `?` or `!`, but it does mean that the `docRef.id` in the `StreamBuilder` will raise an error if `docRef` is still `null` by then.

---

I recommend reading the documentation on [Dart null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety), and other [[questions about this error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=The+non-nullable+local+variable+must+be+assigned+before+it+can+be+used.+Try+giving+it+an+initializer+expression%2C+or+ensure+that+it%27s+assigned+on+every+execution+path.).